# node.js fetch mysql data using two tables

Tags: mysql, node.js

**Table lists**

id | user_id | name

1  | 3 | ListA
2  | 3 | ListB

**Table celebrities**

id  | user_id | list_id | celebrity_code

1   |   3    |  1     | AA000297
2   |   3    |  1     | AA000068
3   |   3    |  2     | AA000214
4   |   3    |  2     | AA000348

I am looking a JSON object like this

[
   {id:1, name:'ListA', celebrities:[{celebrity_code:AA000297},{celebrity_code:AA000068}]},

{id:2, name:'ListB', celebrities:[{celebrity_code:AA000214},{celebrity_code:AA000348}]}
]

Comment: Since you are using MySQL, check out [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). To get your object, you will want to `GROUP_CONCAT` on a `CONCAT`enated string. If you could live with a schema more like `{id:2, name:'ListB', celebrity_codes:['AA000214','AA000348']}` you'll have a simpler query. If you make a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) of your basic schema (basically your create tables plus the inserts of the above sample data), someone might even write it for you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Moved this to an answer since the details were getting long, and I thought the additional references would be useful to future readers.

Since you are using MySQL, check out [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). To get your object, you will want to `GROUP_CONCAT` on a `CONCAT`enated string. If you could live with a schema more like `{id:2, name:'ListB', celebrity_codes:['AA000214','AA000348']}` you'll have a simpler query. If you make a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) of your basic schema (basically your create tables plus the inserts of the above sample data), someone might even write it for you. :-)

To be clear, while `GROUP_CONCAT` can do this, if you are trying to generate more than a fairly simple schema, it gets to be some pretty messy code and it starts making more and more sense to move it into your application layer both from a code maintenance standpoint as well as performance & scalability considerations.

Also note that SQLLite supports `GROUP_CONCAT`, for other databases:

- Postgres user should look at [`string_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)
- SQL Server users should check out [this project on CodePlex](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/).
- Oracle users can use `MODEL`, as [illustrated here](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/05/group_concat-in-oracle-10g/).